# How can I update my southbridge driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

My motherboard is an AMD SB780 model. I think the AMD PCI Express (3GIO) Filter Driver is the northbridge driver. But I can't find the southbridge driver? Where can I download and install the southbridge driver for the AMD SB780 motherboard model? I've found a Southbridge driver package from the AMD website but the Driver folder is empty. I need the southbridge driver because I can't install any driver from AMD website because my box is branded and the brand doesn't support this box anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The southbridge driver is in the nomenklatura the AMD USB Filter Driver and the northbridge driver is AMD PCI Express (3GIO) Filter Driver. You can find them in various packages at the official site.